Route props в vue не работают
Возможно, я не правильно понимаю, что пишут в документации.
Это уже 1000 попытка прописать props.
{
        path: "/user",
        name: "User",
        component: UserProfile,
        props: { default: true, title: "Профиль" },
        children: [
            {
                path: "profile",
                name: "Profile",
                component: UserEditProfile,
                props: { title: "Профиль" },
                meta: { showCloseButton: true },
            },
            {
                path: "favorite",
                name: "Favorite",
                component: MainView,
                props: { title: "Избранное" },
            },
        ],
    },

Очень прошу написать более понятно, чем в документациях.
Мне надо передать название для каждой страницы. И да, оно должно быть в роуте, ну или хотелось бы чтобы оно было в роуте.
{{ route.params }} выводит "пусто".
const props = defineProps({
    title: String,
});

Так же не видит переданных данных.

Насколько я помню, эти параметры нужно передавать в params: {}, а props нужно просто поставить в true, чтобы он переданные параметры автоматически конвертировал в пропы.

класс, а в документации не слова про это, точнее есть, только очень не понятно описано и примеры через одно место

В итоге работает? Можно еще наверное через () => ({title: "My Title"}) попробовать.

нет, не работает, все пусто

Если попробовать не через пропсы обращаться, а через роутер на прямую к параметрам этого роута, то видно их? Вроде {{ $route.params.title }}

Вообще, вот этот пример говорит, что так делать можно
const routes = [   {     path: '/promotion/from-newsletter',     component: Promotion,     props: { newsletterPopup: false }   } ]. Если не работает, то это довольно странно. Попробуйте создать репро где-нибудь на стакблитце, например. Если и там не будет работать, тогда уже можно открывать тикет.

Кстати, еще есть вариант, что пропы попадают не в дочерние компоненты, а в UserProfile, так что советую проверить и его на всякий случай.

везде попробовал, везде undefined
